# Recommender algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, recommender-system

We have some skill levels (beginner, advance, expert) which users assign themselves. Then they get some rating (2, 3, 4, 5) stars from others…. So an expert may have 2-star overall rating and an advance may have a 5-star overall rating. I think advance user with 5-star overall rating should be valued more than expert user with 2-star overall rating.

How can we compose a recommender algorithm with this reversal stuff?

Comment: You could try to infer the ratings iteratively. Let the user i's score $s_i$ be the average of the other users' ratings $s_i' = \dfrac{\sum_j s_j r_{j,i} }{ \sum_j s_j}$, weighted by experience (score).

Comment: @Emre Thanks, but could you explain your thought with some example

Comment: Initialize $s_i$ to a user's self rating, then update it using a weighted average of the user's score by others so skilled users' inputs are more influential. However, the weights themselves are estimated using the same procedure, so you need to iterate until [fixed point convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration). I could be misinterpreting your question, because I'm not proposing a recommender system, but a method to reconcile the user ratings. What is to be recommended?

Comment: @Kirill: From what I understand, in Emre's suggestion, the user's self rating will be very low importance if they have a lot of other ratings. However, if the people giving the star ratings are aware of the first user's own category and rate them accordingly ("I wanted an Expert, but you are not that good, only 2 stars for you!") then Emre's suggested process does not take that into account. But then I am not sure what could . . . perhaps explain your desired outcome - what will this combined rating/value be used for?